# Spawn another terminal running tmux (from a terminal running tmux)

Tags: terminal, tmux, rxvt

I'm currently using urxvt with tmux, run as such:

```
urxvt -e tmux
```

I wish to start up a completely separate instance of `urxvt -e tmux` (another urxvt, also running tmux) using the terminal.  (More precisely, I would like a command that does so, so that I can use it in my terminal-based programs.)  I can't find the right command for this, however.  No matter what I try, the following error occurs:

```
sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force
```

Is there a command, or failing that an indirect method, of starting up a new `urxvt -e tmux` without nesting?  (The second "urxvt" would have nothing to do with the first one; I just wish to trigger the spawning of a second one, also running tmux.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do to do this is (as the error message says) unset the `$TMUX` variable:

```
(unset TMUX; urxvt -e tmux)
```

The subshell is necessary to avoid it being unset in your current environment, too. If you don't care about that, you don't need the subshell.

Comment: How can I tell that it's safe/unsafe to do so?  (Sorry if it's a silly question, but when I looked online I kept seeing people adamant that you shouldn't be unsetting it, and should be avoiding the error instead.)  Also, does it work as well for `(unset TMUX; urxvt -e tmux) &`

Comment: @spacingissue It's safe -- nesting tmux sessions does require some care (you need to think about how to send the prefix easily to the nested sessions, for example), but there's nothing harmful about unsetting TMUX -- it's the normal way to do this. In your case, you're not even nesting. As for your question about backgrounding, yes, that will also work.

Answer (score 0):

Do not type tmux first!  You need to enter your session from Linux ubuntu session.  This is the problem.

So start in the Linux normal command line

and paste this below (adjust the 0 with your session name)

```
tmux attach-session -t 0
```

That is it! Problem solved.  I promise. Just make sure you don't enter tmux before trying to attach a session.  You must be in ubuntu/linux!